# Check if there is a $_GET paramater, if so add new paramater to existing

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function that adds a unique code to every URL on my wordpress website, and adds a url paramater `?refpin=`

I've noticed when going to pages that already have a paramater for example `?s=XXX` it causes a redirect loop and gets stuck.

My function is as follows :

```
function wprdcv_param_redirect(){
    
    $referalpin = $_GET['refpin'];
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && !is_user_admin()){
       if (!$referalpin){
           global $wpdb;
           $ioppin = 
       
      bp_get_profile_field_data('field=211&user_id='.bp_loggedin_user_id());


        $location = esc_url(add_query_arg(array('refpin' => $ioppin,)));
        wp_redirect($location);
       }
    }
 }
    add_action('template_redirect', 'wprdcv_param_redirect');
```

I am wondering what would be the correct way to check if there is an existing paramater, and if there is to simply add the refpin paramater to it, for example `?s=XXX&refpin=IIII`

Comment: _"and if there is to simply add the refpin paramater to it, for example ?s=XXX&refpin=IIII"_ - that is what `add_query_arg` should be doing in the first place. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/#description: _"Omitting the URL from either use results in the current URL being used (the value of $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])."_ Have you actually _verified_ that this resulted in a redirect to a URL that was _missing_ the `s` parameter now?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Yes, It was just doing a redirect issue. Upon further checking i see that its doing the following to the URL

https://xxxxxxxx.com/create/?s=channel&#038;refpin=IOP1


Instead of &?refpin. When i edit the url in the address bar to just &?refpin= it works fine

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know whether or not the URL contains a query string, this statement will return true if there is a query string:

```
!empty($_GET) // Check if any parameters in query string
!empty($_GET['refpin']) // Check if 'refpin' has a value
isset($_GET['refpin']) // Check if 'refpin' is defined with or without a value
```

The [PHP super global variable $_GET](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals_get.asp) is essentially an associative array of all the parameters in the query string.

The way your code is checking for the 'refpin' parameter may throw an error if the variable is not defined (depending on your version of PHP).

As for adding the parameter to the url, i suggest using the function [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

This function accepts an associative array, and returns a query string. Without knowing what the function 'bp_get_profile_field_data' returns, it's difficult to provide a full solution. But if you can manage to break that return value into an array, the 'http_build_query' function will work out nicely for you. Note that you will still need to add the '?' before the start of the query string.

One way to get this done would be to use the [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function. So something like this may do the trick:

```
$query_string = array_merge($_GET ?? [], ['refpin' => 'III'])
$query_string = http_build_query(query_string);
```